# CommandNotFoundException errors in Powershell script

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, curl, terminal, upload

I'm using this script to try to upload files to an S3 bucket using cURL.

```
#S3 parameters
$S3KEY="AKIAYZL7ANTULMU355OD"
$S3SECRET="AKIAYZL7ANTULMU355OD"
$S3BUCKET="quixel-ml-team-data"
$S3STORAGETYPE="STANDARD" #REDUCED_REDUNDANCY or STANDARD etc.
$AWSREGION="us-west-2"

file_path="C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Temp\input_settings.txt"
aws_path="seam-removal\"
bucket="${S3BUCKET}"
date=$(date -R)
acl="x-amz-acl:private"
content_type="application/x-compressed-tar"
storage_type="x-amz-storage-class:${S3STORAGETYPE}"
string="PUT\n\n$content_type\n$date\n$acl\n$storage_type\n/$bucket$aws_path${file_path##/*/}"
signature=$(echo -en "${string}" | openssl sha1 -hmac "${S3SECRET}" -binary | base64)
curl -s --retry 3 --retry-delay 10 -X PUT -T "$file_path" \
    -H "Host: $bucket.${AWSREGION}.amazonaws.com" \
    -H "Date: $date" \
    -H "Content-Type: $content_type" \
    -H "$storage_type" \
    -H "$acl" \
    -H "Authorization: AWS ${S3KEY}:$signature" \
    "https://$bucket.${AWSREGION}.amazonaws.com$aws_path${file_path##/*/}"
```

However, I'm getting these errors. Any idea about them? Sorry, I'm a novice at this sort of programming.

```
file_path=C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Temp\input_settings.txt : The term
'file_path=C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Temp\input_settings.txt' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function,
script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is
correct and try again.
At C:\Users\DELL\Desktop\Abdullah Chand\quixel-ml-khalid-chand\script_upload_to_aws_using_curl.ps1:11 char:1
+ file_path="C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Temp\input_settings.txt"
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (file_path=C:\Us...ut_settings.txt:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

aws_path=seam-removal\ : The term 'aws_path=seam-removal\' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script
file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct
and try again.
At C:\Users\DELL\Desktop\Abdullah Chand\quixel-ml-khalid-chand\script_upload_to_aws_using_curl.ps1:12 char:1
+ aws_path="seam-removal\"
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (aws_path=seam-removal\:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

bucket=${S3BUCKET} : The term 'bucket=${S3BUCKET}' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file,
or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and
try again.
At C:\Users\DELL\Desktop\Abdullah Chand\quixel-ml-khalid-chand\script_upload_to_aws_using_curl.ps1:13 char:1
+ bucket="${S3BUCKET}"
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (bucket=${S3BUCKET}:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

date=$(date -R) : The term 'date=$(date -R)' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or
operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try
again.
At C:\Users\DELL\Desktop\Abdullah Chand\quixel-ml-khalid-chand\script_upload_to_aws_using_curl.ps1:14 char:1
+ date=$(date -R)
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (date=$(date -R):String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

acl=x-amz-acl:private : The term 'acl=x-amz-acl:private' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script
file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct
and try again.
At C:\Users\DELL\Desktop\Abdullah Chand\quixel-ml-khalid-chand\script_upload_to_aws_using_curl.ps1:15 char:1
+ acl="x-amz-acl:private"
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (acl=x-amz-acl:private:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

content_type=application/x-compressed-tar : The term 'content_type=application/x-compressed-tar' is not recognized as
the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was
included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At C:\Users\DELL\Desktop\Abdullah Chand\quixel-ml-khalid-chand\script_upload_to_aws_using_curl.ps1:16 char:1
+ content_type="application/x-compressed-tar"
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (content_type=ap...-compressed-tar:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

storage_type=x-amz-storage-class:${S3STORAGETYPE} : The term 'storage_type=x-amz-storage-class:${S3STORAGETYPE}' is
not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or
if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At C:\Users\DELL\Desktop\Abdullah Chand\quixel-ml-khalid-chand\script_upload_to_aws_using_curl.ps1:17 char:1
+ storage_type="x-amz-storage-class:${S3STORAGETYPE}"
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (storage_type=x-...{S3STORAGETYPE}:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

string=PUT\n\n$content_type\n$date\n$acl\n$storage_type\n/$bucket$aws_path${file_path##/*/} : The module 'string=PUT'
could not be loaded. For more information, run 'Import-Module string=PUT'.
At C:\Users\DELL\Desktop\Abdullah Chand\quixel-ml-khalid-chand\script_upload_to_aws_using_curl.ps1:18 char:1
+ string="PUT\n\n$content_type\n$date\n$acl\n$storage_type\n/$bucket$aw ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (string=PUT\n\n$...file_path##/*/}:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CouldNotAutoLoadModule

signature=$(echo -en "${string}" | openssl sha1 -hmac "${S3SECRET}" -binary | base64) : The term 'signature=$(echo -en
"${string}" | openssl sha1 -hmac "${S3SECRET}" -binary | base64)' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function,
script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is
correct and try again.
At C:\Users\DELL\Desktop\Abdullah Chand\quixel-ml-khalid-chand\script_upload_to_aws_using_curl.ps1:19 char:1
+ signature=$(echo -en "${string}" | openssl sha1 -hmac "${S3SECRET}" - ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (signature=$(ech...inary | base64):String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

Invoke-WebRequest : Parameter cannot be processed because the parameter name 'T' is ambiguous. Possible matches
include: -TimeoutSec -TransferEncoding.
At C:\Users\DELL\Desktop\Abdullah Chand\quixel-ml-khalid-chand\script_upload_to_aws_using_curl.ps1:20 char:43
+ curl -s --retry 3 --retry-delay 10 -X PUT -T "$file_path" \
+                                           ~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Invoke-WebRequest], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : AmbiguousParameter,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeWebRequestCommand

-H : The term '-H' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the
spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At C:\Users\DELL\Desktop\Abdullah Chand\quixel-ml-khalid-chand\script_upload_to_aws_using_curl.ps1:21 char:5
+     -H "Host: $bucket.${AWSREGION}.amazonaws.com" \
+     ~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (-H:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

-H : The term '-H' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the
spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At C:\Users\DELL\Desktop\Abdullah Chand\quixel-ml-khalid-chand\script_upload_to_aws_using_curl.ps1:22 char:5
+     -H "Date: $date" \
+     ~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (-H:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

-H : The term '-H' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the
spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At C:\Users\DELL\Desktop\Abdullah Chand\quixel-ml-khalid-chand\script_upload_to_aws_using_curl.ps1:23 char:5
+     -H "Content-Type: $content_type" \
+     ~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (-H:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

-H : The term '-H' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the
spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At C:\Users\DELL\Desktop\Abdullah Chand\quixel-ml-khalid-chand\script_upload_to_aws_using_curl.ps1:24 char:5
+     -H "$storage_type" \
+     ~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (-H:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

-H : The term '-H' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the
spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At C:\Users\DELL\Desktop\Abdullah Chand\quixel-ml-khalid-chand\script_upload_to_aws_using_curl.ps1:25 char:5
+     -H "$acl" \
+     ~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (-H:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

-H : The term '-H' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the
spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At C:\Users\DELL\Desktop\Abdullah Chand\quixel-ml-khalid-chand\script_upload_to_aws_using_curl.ps1:26 char:5
+     -H "Authorization: AWS ${S3KEY}:$signature" \
```

- ```
  ~~
  ```

  - CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (-H:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
  - FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're mixing a PowerShell with a traditional Unix script.

Further, there's no need to call out the external utilities like OpenSSL and Curl since PowerShell has similar capabilities built in.  To sign the URL and perform the Upload without using the AWS SDK, the script would look something like this:

```
$method = 'PUT'
$service = 's3'
$bucket = "SAMPLES3BUCKETNAME"
$key = 'example-s3-key.txt'
$local_file = "test.txt"
$region = 'us-west-2'
$host1 = $bucket + '.s3-' + $region + '.amazonaws.com'
$access_key = 'SAMPLEACCESSKEY'
$secret_key = 'SAMPLESECRETKEY'

function HmacSHA256($message, $secret)
{
    $hmacsha = New-Object System.Security.Cryptography.HMACSHA256
    $hmacsha.key = $secret
    $signature = $hmacsha.ComputeHash([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes($message))

    return $signature
}

function getSignatureKey($key, $dateStamp, $regionName, $serviceName)
{
    $kSecret = [Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes(("AWS4" + $key).toCharArray())
    $kDate = HmacSHA256 $dateStamp $kSecret;
    $kRegion = HmacSHA256 $regionName $kDate;
    $kService = HmacSHA256 $serviceName $kRegion;
    $kSigning = HmacSHA256 "aws4_request" $kService;

    return $kSigning
}

function hash($request)
{
    $hasher = [System.Security.Cryptography.SHA256]::Create()
    $content = [Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes($request)
    $bytes = $hasher.ComputeHash($content)

    return ($bytes|ForEach-Object ToString x2) -join ''
}

$now = [DateTime]::UtcNow
$amz_date = $now.ToString('yyyyMMddTHHmmssZ')
$datestamp = $now.ToString('yyyyMMdd')

$signed_headers = 'host'
$credential_scope = $datestamp + '/' + $region + '/' + $service + '/' + 'aws4_request'

$canonical_querystring = 'X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256'
$canonical_querystring += '&X-Amz-Credential=' + [uri]::EscapeDataString(($access_key + '/' + $credential_scope))
$canonical_querystring += '&X-Amz-Date=' + $amz_date
$canonical_querystring += '&X-Amz-Expires=300'
$canonical_querystring += '&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=' + $signed_headers

$canonical_headers = 'host:' + $host1 + "`n"

$canonical_request = $method + "`n"
$canonical_request += "/" + $key + "`n"
$canonical_request += $canonical_querystring + "`n"
$canonical_request += $canonical_headers + "`n"
$canonical_request += $signed_headers + "`n"
$canonical_request += "UNSIGNED-PAYLOAD"

$algorithm = 'AWS4-HMAC-SHA256'

$canonical_request_hash = hash -request $canonical_request
$string_to_sign = $algorithm + "`n"
$string_to_sign += $amz_date + "`n"
$string_to_sign += $credential_scope + "`n"
$string_to_sign += $canonical_request_hash

$signing_key = getSignatureKey $secret_key $datestamp $region $service
$signature =  HmacSHA256 -secret $signing_key -message $string_to_sign
$signature = ($signature|ForEach-Object ToString x2) -join ''

$canonical_querystring += '&X-Amz-Signature=' + $signature

$request_url = "http://" + $host1 + "/" + $key + "?" + $canonical_querystring

# Write-Host $request_url

# Using Curl:
# curl.exe '-s', '--retry', '3', '--retry-delay', '10', '-X', 'PUT', '-T', $local_file, $request_url

# Or just put to the URL directly:
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $request_url -Method Put -InFile $local_file
```